How to import python in kotlin?(android studio)
I want to import python in android studio, using chaquopy. I installed python 3.8.0 and put it in the same directory as the specified directory, and I got error message 'Unresolved reference: buildPython'. Is there any library I have to plugin in build.gradle?
Here's the code below.

build.gradle.kts(Project)

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven("https://chaquo.com/maven")
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.7.2") 
        classpath("com.chaquo.python:gradle:16.0.0")
    }
}

plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "7.4.0" apply false // Android Application Plugin
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.10" apply false // Kotlin Android Plugin
    id("com.chaquo.python") version "16.0.0" apply false
}


build.gradle.kts(Module)

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") 
    id("com.chaquo.python")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.test"
    compileSdk = 35

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.test"
        minSdk = 31
        targetSdk = 35
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        buildPython = "C:/Python38/python.exe"

        ndk {
            abiFilters += listOf("arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86_64",  "x86")
        }
    }
    
chaquopy{
    defaultConfig {
        version = "3.8"
        buildPython("C:/Test_241115_23/Test/app/python/test.py", "-3.8")
        extractPackages("")
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Kotlin standard library
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:2.0.21")
   }

I appreciate your help.

Try removing the buildPython inside the android block, and placing the C:/Python38/python.exe in the buildPython() argument inside the chaquopy block (it should refer to the python binary, not to the python code file)

Thanks to your help! it worked helpfully.
